# What is Shia view about Interpretation of verse 24 of surat An-Nisa'(4:24)?

Tags: nikah, tafseer, shiism, surat-an-nisa

Verse 24 of surat An-Nisa'say:

> وَ الْمُحْصَناتُ مِنَ النِّساءِ إِلاَّ ما مَلَکَتْ أَيْمانُکُمْ کِتابَ
>   اللَّهِ عَلَيْکُمْ وَ أُحِلَّ لَکُمْ ما وَراءَ ذلِکُمْ أَنْ تَبْتَغُوا
>   بِأَمْوالِکُمْ مُحْصِنينَ غَيْرَ مُسافِحينَ فَمَا اسْتَمْتَعْتُمْ بِهِ
>   مِنْهُنَّ فَآتُوهُنَّ أُجُورَهُنَّ فَريضَةً وَ لا جُناحَ عَلَيْکُمْ
>   فيما تَراضَيْتُمْ بِهِ مِنْ بَعْدِ الْفَريضَةِ إِنَّ اللَّهَ کانَ
>   عَليماً حَکيماً
>
> And all married women except those whom your right hands possess (this
>   is) Allah's ordinance to you, and lawful for you are (all women)
>   besides those, provided that you seek (them) with your property,
>   taking (them) in marriage not committing fornication. Then as to those
>   whom you profit by, give them their dowries as appointed; and there is
>   no blame on you about what you mutually agree after what is appointed;
>   surely Allah is Knowing, Wise.(4:24)

As I searched, there are 2 interpretations for this verse.

One interprets the verse to be about permanent marriage (Tafsir al-Manar of Rashid Reza)

And one interprets to be about temporary marriage (mut’ah)(Tafseer Kabeer of Tabari,al-Kashāf of Al-Zamakhshari,the sharh (explanation) of Sahih Muslim by Nawawi)

So, which one is the correct interpretation in Shia view? Please provide strong reasons.

Answer (score -1):

```
             In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

In regards to Surah An-Nisa, verse 24, I presume the following illustration can elucidate the issue for you to some extent:

> For non-Muslims, captivity is counted as divorce. It is like the Faith
>   of a woman that when her husband continues his infidelity and the
>   woman has embraced Islam; the very belief separates her from her
>   husband. To take in marriage a woman who has husband is unlawful from the point
>   of Islam. The woman may be from any nation and with any religion.
>
> But captivity is like divorce, and a captive woman should observe a
>   waiting term for one month (one menstruation) from the time she is
>   captured, and if she is in pregnancy period, she must wait until she
>   is delivered of her child. Thus, during this period, no conjugal
>   connection is admissible with her. This matrimonial device, as a permanent or contemporary spouse, is
>   better than the device of returning her to the infidels or leaving her
>   alone with no guardian.
>
> "..." , According to several traditions
>   narrated from the holy Imams of Ahlul-Bayt (as), and also according to
>   many commentary books recorded by the scholars of the Sunnis, this
>   phrase of the verse refers to temporary marriage where the
>   above-mentioned holy verse says:
>
> "...Then as to those of Whom you seek content (by marriage), give them
>   their dowries as a duty. And there is no blame on you in whatever you
>   mutually agree after the duty. Verily Allah is All-Knowing, All-Wise."

---

**Reference and further information:**

- [https://www.al-islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/enlightening-commentary-light-holy-quran-vol-4/surah-nisa-chapter-4-section-4)
- http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/14401

Answer (score -2):

The interpretation referring to temporary marriage(mut’ah) is the correct Shia view. You can read it from [here](http://www.almizan.org/).

Comment: would you please note just the important points of this link which could prove your answer?

Comment: I saw the link. It seems helpful, but I wish you add it in your answer  directly.